# iOS - removing subview that added programmatically and printing date in label

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker

I need some help related to iOS application

On clicking the button I added a DatePicker programmatically and now I am not able to remove the view this is my code

I also tried to put the date in label dateLabel but it shows some run time error because it is not a string format I tried some other method also like NSDateFormatter but I am not getting the proper result

```
-(IBAction)date:(id)sender{

    UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 320, 300, 500)];

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Pick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

    NSData *date=[datePicker date];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    dateLabel.text=date;
}

-(void)Pick:(id)sender{

    [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Instaed of action of datePicker you have to take a UIButton after change the date you needed then you clikc on the button then in button action you have to get selecteddate value and you have to remove datePicker from its superview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
-(IBAction)date:(id)sender
{
   datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 320, 300, 500)];
   [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Pick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}

-(void)Pick:(id)sender
  {
     NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
     label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                     [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
     [df release];
   [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
    datePicker=nil;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Declare your datepicker in .h

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

and then

```
-(IBAction)date:(id)sender
{
   datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 320, 300, 500)];
   [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Pick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
}

-(void)Pick:(id)sender
  {
     NSDate *date=[datePicker date];
     NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];
    NSString *dateSTr = [dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateSTr);
    dateLabel.text=date;
   [datePicker removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

Comment: the view disappears but it doen't print the date in label it shows this error -[__NSDATE isEqualToString:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance0x9242ce0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use @property for `datePicker` as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `UIDatePicker *datePicker` as a local variable.

It can be only accessible in the declared function (`-(IBAction)date:(id)sender`).

You need to declare it globally for using it in other functions.

Declare that variable in your .m file under

```
@interface className()
  @property(nonatomic, strong) UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@end
```